# Replace theme search functionality with woocommerce search

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, themes

Is there a way that i can overwrite theme's search query with woocommerce product search. I want instead of search content in pages and post, it will search only in products.

I searched and found this:

```
    function custom_search_query($where, &$wp_query)
    {
        global $wpdb;

        if ( empty( $where ))
            return $where;

        // get search expression
        $terms = $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ];


        $where = 'wp_posts.post_type = "product"';

        // get searcheable_acf, a list of advanced custom fields you want to search content in
        $list_searcheable_acf = list_searcheable_acf();
        foreach( $exploded as $tag ) :
            $where .= " 
              AND (
                (wp_posts.post_type LIKE '%$tag%')
                OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$tag%')
                OR EXISTS (
                  SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta
                      WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID
                        AND (";
            foreach ($list_searcheable_acf as $searcheable_acf) :
              if ($searcheable_acf == $list_searcheable_acf[0]):
                $where .= " (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%') ";
              else :
                $where .= " OR (meta_key LIKE '%" . $searcheable_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%') ";
              endif;
            endforeach;
                $where .= ")
                )
                OR EXISTS (
                  SELECT * FROM wp_comments
                  WHERE comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID
                    AND comment_content LIKE '%$tag%'
                )
                OR EXISTS (
                  SELECT * FROM wp_terms
                  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
                    ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
                  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
                    ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
                  WHERE (
                    taxonomy = 'post_tag'
                        OR taxonomy = 'category'                
                        OR taxonomy = 'myCustomTax'
                    )
                    AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%$tag%'
                )
            )";
        endforeach;
        return $where;
    }
    add_filter( 'posts_search', 'custom_search_query', 500, 2 );
```

But this will add advance custom fields in search.. I want to search only for products.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter to filter the post types in search results page. For example:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );
function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

The only problem here is that if your product have custom fields or attributes, they will not be included in result because the default WordPress search looks only in title and content.
The example you have provided has more complex search and it looks in custom fields too. But if the main goal is to remove everything except products, my code will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works like a charm.. I was looking for solution from past 8 hours.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code below should search only the "product" post type, and will display in your normal search archive. By using the 'post_type' in the name attribute you can declare what post types to search.

```
 <form action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>" method="get" class="form-inline searchform">    
    <input type="text"  name="s" value="" placeholder="Search for Products..." class="s" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="product" />
    <button type="submit" class="searchsubmit">Search</button>    
</form>
```